# iOS: dateformatter for countdown timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I am trying to implement a countdown timer in iOS- i.e. On passing a particular date of future, a timer should be displayed- e.g. `2 days, 4 hours, 17 minutes remaining` from current date.

For this I am using the following code:

**in viewDidLoad:**

```
// start a timer
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And the timer method:

```
 - (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    // has the target time passed?
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *targetDate = [NSDate date];

    NSString *strDate = [[self campaignDetail] objectForKey:@"expire_date"];
    NSLog(@"%@", strDate); // 06/06/2014 19:00:00
    targetDate = [df dateFromString: strDate];
// targetDate comes as nil when I NSLog this. I think this is causing the problem

    if ([targetDate earlierDate:now] == targetDate) {
        [theTimer invalidate];
    } else {
        NSUInteger flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:now toDate:targetDate options:0];
//        [self.labelTime_left setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds remaining", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]]];
        NSLog(@"there are %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds remaining", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]);
    }
}
```

The timer method is fired, but when i debug and NSLog targetDate, I get it as nil. Please see the code above to see where I get it as nil.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: NSDate objects are immutable. Try commenting out the NSDate *targetDate line and adding the 'NSDate *' to the beginning of the 'targetDate =' assignment.

Comment: Yes I tried this too: NSDate *targetDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString]; Still it gets nil value. Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: [df dateFromString: strDate] will return nil if the dateFormatter cannot parse the string. Verify that the string matches the format.